# Pkg-Config Error (No such file or directory)

Tags: 12.04, gtk3, pkg-config

if i try and compile the tutorial code for GTK3 with the command

```
gcc simple.c -o simple 'pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0'
```

it gives off the error

```
gcc: error: pkg-config --libs --cflag gtk+-3.0: No such file or directory
```

However if i run the command

```
pkg-config --libs --cflag gtk+-3.0 > makefile
```

and then edit the makefile such that the output of the above command is after

```
gcc simple.c -o simple
```

then it compiles with no problems at all. What gives?

Answer (score 5):

I got this problem too, but after carefully see the the code, it just a typo.
Please see again your command,

```
gcc simple.c -o simple 'pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0'
```

It should be,

```
gcc simple.c -o simple `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

Can you see the different? The '  should be `. It works for me!

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution worked for me. +1

Comment: It took more than 10 minutes to understood the difference between those two lines ( Just a hint for others , it is the **`** mark before pkg-config and after gtk+-3.0)